# how to start the column naming from position 1

Tags: java, columnheader

I have the following

```
uniqueStrings.stream().forEach(modelR::addColumn);
```

uniqueStrings is simply a treeset of data.

and each of the uniqueStrings creates a header name for each column of my table.

Im not really use to the new Java8 notation but how would i start the column naming from the 2nd column rather than the first.

```
uniqueStrings.stream().forEach(modelR::addColumn); 

        modelR.setRowCount(dataList.size());
        int row = 0;
        int col = 1;
        for (Data data : dataList) {

            modelR.setValueAt(data.hhh1, row, col);

          col++;
        }
        tableR.setModel(modelR);
```

Someone momentarily added this

```
Stream.concat(Stream.of(""), uniqueStrings.stream()).forEach(modelR::addColumn);
```

and then deleted it, it works - please can you let me know who you are so you can claim the answer

Comment: do you want it to loop back to one like `2 3 4 5 1` or do you want `2 1 3 4 5`?

Comment: The current issue is that i am putting my data starting from the 2nd column into the table. However i am adding my columns and naming them starting from the 1st column, therefore the header title is shifted one to the left. I want to shift the header one to the right. The first column will ultimately used for like a row header (without going through the difficulties of row header implementation

Comment: I have added to my question